# how to find the middle element of the map?? STL

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi I am stuck in between the concept of Map in STL Library/C++.

```
int arr[] = {10,15,14,13,17,15,16,12,18,10,29,24,35,36};
int n = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;

map<int, bool> bst;
map<int, bool>::iterator it;
vector<int> median_output;

const int k = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    bst.insert(make_pair(arr[i], true));
}

for (it = bst.begin(); it != bst.end(); it++) {
    cout << (*it).first << " ";
}
```

Now when i printed this map, it got printed in sorted Order. Now is there any simplest way to find the middle of this map.....
Need to find the median of a bigger problem... So trying to implement balanced binary search tree..

Comment: an augmented binary search tree supports O(log n) query for k-th element. but stl implementation does not have that by default and (i guess) it is not possible to use the existing tree code in stl to archives that. you have to write your own balanced BSTs for this kind of query.

Comment: Do you really need a map, or do you just want to find the median of a sequence?

Comment: +1. Excellent question. I would add that O(log n) solution is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` **is** a balanced search tree. To find it's middle - find it's size, and iterate from the `begin()` for half it's size - that will be the middle. Something like this:

```
for (it = bst.begin(), int middle = 0; middle < bst.size()/2; it++, middle++) {
    cout << (*it).first << " ";
}

// now after the loop it is the median.
```

If you use `map` to sort things - then it's an overkill, IMHO. You can do it much more effectively with an array (or `vector`), and then finding the middle will be trivial as well. `map` is used for accessing data by key, not just sorting.

Comment: I fully don't understand why you kept the map for sorting, and feel the need to iterate instead of just saying `std::advance(bst.begin(), bst.size()/2)`

Comment: I kept the map because that's what the question was about. As to `std::advance` - the only benefit it provides is the concealing of the loop (and thus making the code more "nice" and safer from various bugs), but the point is to show what's done here.

Comment: Your solution is O(n). I think OP knows how to iterate. Obviously  O(log n) solution is needed.

Comment: @Alexey - for that OP has to implement his own tree.

Comment: I don't understood the need of iterating instead of using advance.. can @littleadv or @sehe but sum light on it........ Actually what i feel if advance is used,,, guessing on the implementation behind advance,, you need not traverse the BST from start again.... ???

Comment: @littleadv - yes, may be has to, may be has not to. I think OP asks if it is possible simply, the easy way.

Comment: @AGeek - there's no functional difference between using `advance` and iterating - they do exactly the same, except that if you iterate - you write your own code, and `advance` is a prebuilt template. I used a snipped of your own code in the example, so you see the loop, @Michael below wrote example from scratch and used `advance`, but they do the same. Re reversing - I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: @Alexey - if you have an idea not yet mentioned in the answers - just feel free to add one

Comment: @AGeek: `advance()` is a function template that knows how to 'best' move an iterator.  If the iterator is random access (like for a vector or deque) it'll just perform the O(1) operation to move the iterator.  If the iterator is less capable (like the bi-directional iterator for `std::map`) it'll loop over incrementing the iterator and will be an O(N) operation.

Answer (score 6):

With the code shown you are abusing the map to sort the keys.

You can get much more performance, avoiding full sort and copy:

```
   const int len = 14;
   const int a[len] = {10,15,14,13,17,15,16,12,18,10,29,24,35,36};

   std::nth_element( a, a+len/2, a+len );
   std::cout << "Median: " << a[len/2] << std::endl;
```

If you prefer to use STL containers, your code would look like this (assuming a container with random access iterators):

```
   std::vector<int> v( a, a+len );
   std::nth_element( v.begin(), v.begin()+len/2,v.end() );
   std::cout << "Median: " << v[len/2] << std::endl;
```

Comment: A bit wasteful (and confusing) to use `std::nth_element` AND `std::sort`. I'd say use one or the other.

Comment: If there's no other reason for the `map` except to get the sequence sorted, then this is the best answer.  Actually, there's not even a need for the vector - `nth_element()` will work directly on the array (if it's left non-const): `nth_element( arr, arr + len/2, arr + len)`

Comment: @sehe OK point taken, but maybe you can explain that in the text of the answer? Currently you only mention "full sort and copy". Could be confusing to OP...

Comment: Slightly adapted answer showing more subtleties that the OP wasn't asking about :)

Comment: @sehe: `nth_element()` won't work on a `std:list` since it requires random access iterators.

Comment: @Michael: Ah ... my bad. I was over-generalizing

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` might not be the best container for locating the median.  But this will do the trick pretty simply:

```
it = bst.begin();
advance( it, bst.size() / 2);
cout << endl << "median: " << it->first << endl;
```

Comment: what is the time complexity involved in advance??

Comment: The time complexity of `advance()` on a `std::map` would be O(N).

Answer (score 0):

std::maps can not give you medians in one shot. If you want medians you need to use [this algorithm](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/research/CG/applets/linear_prog/median.html).

Comment: From the linked page: `CAVEAT EMPTOR [...] A better place to look would be somewhere else (I am too lazy to find the right reference, OK?)`... (sic)

Comment: The algorithm you cite is a simplification of `std::partial_sort`.  If the elements are in an array, something like `std::partial_sort(v.begin(), v.begin() + v.size() / 2 + 1, v.end())` will put the median at `v.begin() + v.size() / 2`.

Comment: incidentally you'll be coming pretty close to reimplementing `std::nth_element` IYAM